# Find duplicate records in MySQL 2

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data, duplicates

All the guys probably will recommend that I read the follow previously question in this URL http://senta.la/bd08

So I'm just read them carefully and I'm still with my problem. This situation its not equals of the question mentioned in link above.

See below the records I want to found (marked with *):

```
ID         COURSE       OTHERCOLUMN_X      OTHERCOLUMN_Y       OTHERCOLUMN_Z
123        2111         ...                ...                 ...
*5644      2245         ...                ...                 ...
*5644      2245         ...                ...                 ...
2121       2131         ...                ...                 ...
```

The previously programmer not thinking use the UNIQUE index to make a compost key to prevent this situation. I know... the good news is that programmer is not a programmer anymore.

This classic query its not provide the result I want...

```
SELECT id, course FROM mytable
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

I want to see only this results:

```
ID         COURSE       OTHERCOLUMN_X      OTHERCOLUMN_Y       OTHERCOLUMN_Z
*5644      2245         ...                ...                 ...
*5644      2245         ...                ...                 ...
```

I'm just tried a lot of queries but I can find one that show me the results above.

:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find rows with duplicate `id`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable AS a
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id 
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY id 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS b
    ON b.id = a.id
```

To find rows with duplicate `(id, course)`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable AS a
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id, course 
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY id, course 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS b
    ON  b.id = a.id
    AND b.course = a.course
```

Answer (score 1):

Well given

```
SELECT id, course FROM mytable GROUP BY id  HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

works one way is to join back to the original table

Something like

```
Select myTable.ID,myTable.Course,... From myTable
inner join(SELECT id, course FROM mytable GROUP BY id  HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) duplicates
On duplicates.id = mytable.id and duplicates.course = mytable.course
```

maybe

Answer (score 1):

try to use following:

```
SELECT id, 
COUNT(id) AS NumOccurrences
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY id
HAVING ( COUNT(id) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
SELECT id, course 
FROM mytable
WHERE id in (SELECT id from mytable GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) > 1)
```